# poor accuracy score on classfication problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science

I'm trying to build a classification model and **my target is not binary**. The **correlations of my features against my target are all weak** (mostly 0.1). I have preprocessed my data and applied the all the algorithms i used to it (the algorithms i used are `svm, knn, naivebayes,logistic regression, decision tree,gradient boosting, random forest`). I evaluated all of the models with  `sklearn metrics.accuracy_score` just to know how good they perform on my data but all of them scored 0.1~0.2 .  The target is `productline` column.
[image: my data]

My questions

1. How could this happen?
2. How to tackle this issue?
3. Is there any other algorithm that could make better score?

Comment: Accuracy is for classification, but it seems like you are doing regression so you must use a different metric. Common choices are mean squared error, Pearson correlation, R squared, Matthews correlation coefficient, etc.

Comment: But what i'm classifying is whether the predicted would be type of product (like home, food, sport, health, electronic, etc) isn't it classification?

Comment: Ah sorry, totally misunderstood your question! Compare loss on train and test set, if they are very different then you are overfitting and must regularize more

Comment: @BlackBear there's overfitting, i have not regularized it yet.. i'm afraid even after regularization the model accuracy would only be approximately 60%.. and i'm still confused of how much score needed to say that the model is 'good' enough. But is the poor performance caused by the very uncorrelated data?

Comment: What features are you using? I hope you didn't use the `data` field as a feature. Also, is your accuracy score based on evaluating the training data or the validation/test data?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 you mean `date` field as a feature? No, it's my index and i do not use it as my feature. It's based on test data. There's overfitting, i have not regularized it yet, i'm afraid even after regularization the model still wouldn't make a 'good' score

Comment: @potatostudent: If you are certain you are overfitting and are citing your test accuracy (rather than training accuracy), then it's fine to add regularization. When used correctly, it will lower the training accuracy but increase the test accuracy To make see if it's a "good" score, you need to compare your result to some other default model. You said that none of the ML models you used worked for you, so choose a simple model like (a) random choice, (b) choose-most-frequent label, or (c) choose random label proportionally to its frequency.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 oh i see, i haven't heard or tried `so choose a simple model like (a) random choice, (b) choose-most-frequent label, or (c) choose random label proportionally to its frequency.` since you mentioned it. would you mind giving me reference to that so i could learn and try it?

Comment: @potatostudent: Use the link provided in the answer post: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html  Its available options that correspond to my suggestions are `uniform`, `most_frequent`, and `stratified`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

What's the accuracy if you use a [dummy classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html)? The accuracy of the models you have tried should be at least equal to that of the dummy classifier.

"How could this happen?" If there's no relationship between the features and the target variable, the model isn't going to return good results.

I'm not sure about the details of your dataset, but you can try to 1) Get more data 2) Get more features 3) Do some feature engineering 4) Clean your dataset if you haven't, there might be outliers or wrong inputs affecting your results